# Problems starting a 2009 Macbook pro

Tags: macos, boot, mac, laptop, macbook

Here is the situation: my macbook pro mid 2009 is a pain to start!

It won't start (the fans won't even turn) if it's cold. So here is what I do:

- I heat it a little bit (let it under warm bed sheet for like 10 minutes),
- then remove the battery,
- hit the start button for 10 seconds,
- plug the battery again,
- then when I hit the start button the fans start turning , but the mac fails to start, sometimes the grey screen comes up, but the boot fails,
- after 10 attempts or so, the macbook finally boot normally, and works just fine (the screen flickers sometimes, but that's an old thing)
- as long as the mac is warm, I could restart it normally

If it goes cold again, then I would have go through all the previous steps.

How could I solve this?

Comment: What happens if you plug it in?  Is it still on the original battery?  When you say "cold", are you talking about normal human room temperature or using it outside in Antarctica?

Comment: Cold = around 15° Celcius, sometimes when I plug it in it's still on the battery. I've reset the SMC several times with no luck so far.